# Canonical way to prevent many to many join table from having duplicates when joining with self

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, many-to-many

I'm modeling a school for a databases project, and I have a many to many relationship, joining a `course` table with itself to establish prerequisites. The table (simplified) looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE course_prereqs (
  course_id INT NOT NULL,
  prereq_id INT NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (course_id, prereq_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (course_id) REFERENCES course (course_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (prereq_id) REFERENCES course (course_id)
)
```

What I was wondering is the simplest, but also most user friendly way you can prevent the both `(1, 2), and (2, 1)` being prerequisites in the table because it'd cause a cyclical dependency.

I was thinking something equivalent to

```
-- in a trigger though since MySQL doesn't have check
CHECK (course_id < prereq_id)
```

but while that works, I feel like it could potentially be annoying for the end user to always make sure that the `course_id` always be less than the `prereq_id`.

Is there a better way, or am I overestimating the inconvenience of having to make sure the `course_id` is always smaller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like an application problem.  When saying "course #1 is a 'prerequisite' for course #2" it is incorrect to later say that "course #2 is a prerequisite for #1.".  That is, why do you need for the database to check something that should never happen?

If, on the other hand, the 'relation' were reflexive (1->2 implies 2->1), then I would do this:

```
INSERT IGNORE (a, b) VALUES (LEAST($this, $that), GREATEST($this, $that));
```

so that there is a 'canonical' order for storing the relationship.  Testing becomes messier.

Or...  Store both relations.  It is only twice as many rows but lookup performance does not suffer noticeably.

In both cases, you need two indexes:

```
PRIMARY KEY(a, b),
INDEX      (b, a)
```

Comment: That all makes sense, but...hmm...why is it an application problem? Isn't it the database's job to enforce the fact that two courses cannot be prereqs for each other? For example, a trigger that throws an error if the select statement in the other answer is not equal to 0.

Comment: @AR7 - The database cannot tell "course" from "prerequisite".  So if #1 is really a prerequisite of #2, but you _first_ insert course=1, prerequisite=2 it won't be caught.  Later, the _correct_ insert of prerequisite=1, course=2 will be flagged as the error.

Answer (score 0):

Before inserting new course check that cnt = 0

```
select count(1) cnt from course_prereqs where course_id = new_prereq_id and prereq_id = new_course_id
```